# BitLocker: A valid USB key wasn't detected

Tags: windows, security, onedrive, bitlocker, microsoft-onedrive

I was using OneDrive and I have uninstalled it.

After having uninstalled it an `E:\` drive appeared but I cannot access it:

[image]

```
Load key from USB drive
A valid USB key wasn't detected
```

Is there any way I can access or mount that drive?

Answer (score 0):

- *If like me you have deleted OneDrive and you think you have lost the whole content of the Personal Vault.*
- *If you think there is no way to access that `E:\` drive partition which is probably a virtual drive.*
- *If you are in despair because you didn't take a backup and you don't have your BitLocker Recovery Key and there is no way to bypass BitLocker encryption.*

Look no further...

Just go to `System Restore` and go back to a previous version of your Windows OS where OneDrive was still installed:

[image]

And you will be able to access the Private Vault just entering your Windows PIN as usual.

All my files where still there.

I'm so happy I wrote a [post](https://www.jeeja.biz/2023/08/31/onedrive-personal-vault-a-bitlocker-odyssey/) about it.